# InvalidArgumentError while using SupervisedContrastiveLoss in Keras

Tags: python, keras, model, classification, loss-function

I am trying to implement the Keras code for supervised contrastive learning as available at https://keras.io/examples/vision/supervised-contrastive-learning/ using a custom dataset. However, the Keras example uses CIFAR-10 dataset and works with the train and test inputs of size and shape as mentioned below and trains the model to optimize sparse categorical cross-entropy loss:

```
x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3) - y_train shape: (50000, 1)
x_test shape: (10000, 32, 32, 3) - y_test shape: (10000, 1)
```

In my case, I have one-hot encoded the labels, so that the size and shape are as shown below and I tend to optimize the categorical cross entropy loss:

```
x_train shape: (1919, 256, 256, 3) - y_train shape: (1919, 2)
x_test shape: (476, 256, 256, 3) - y_test shape: (476, 2)
```

I trained a base VGG-16 based classifier with two output nodes and softmax activation on these data to minimize the categorical cross-entropy loss and obtained some classification performance.

Then I followed the Keras example code to perform Supervised contrastive learning. In the first phase, I truncated the VGG16 model in the deepest convolutional layer and added the projection head to optimize the supervised contrastive loss. The complete code is shown below:

```
    # Supervised contrastive learning loss function
    class SupervisedContrastiveLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
        def __init__(self, temperature=1, name=None):
            super(SupervisedContrastiveLoss, self).__init__(name=name)
            self.temperature = temperature
    
        def __call__(self, labels, feature_vectors, sample_weight=None):
            # Normalize feature vectors
            feature_vectors_normalized = tf.math.l2_normalize(feature_vectors, axis=1)
            # Compute logits
            logits = tf.divide(
                tf.matmul(
                    feature_vectors_normalized, tf.transpose(feature_vectors_normalized)
                ),
                self.temperature,
            )
            return tfa.losses.npairs_loss(tf.squeeze(labels), logits)
    #%%
    #add projection head and train model
    vgg16 = keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
                                     input_tensor=model_input)
    base_model_vgg16=Model(inputs=vgg16.input,outputs=vgg16.get_layer('block5_conv3').output)
    x = base_model_vgg16.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(projection_units, activation="relu")(x)
    encoder_with_projection_head = keras.Model(inputs=vgg16.input, outputs=outputs, 
                                               name="vgg16-encoder_with_projection-head")
    encoder_with_projection_head.summary()   
    
    #%%
    #train the model
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)  
    encoder_with_projection_head.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss=SupervisedContrastiveLoss(temperature))
    filepath = 'weights1/' + encoder_with_projection_head.name + '.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}.h5'
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, 
                                  save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=True, 
                                  mode='min', save_freq='epoch')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    t=time.time()
    encoder_with_projection_head_history = encoder_with_projection_head.fit(
datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=batch_size),
steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
callbacks=callbacks_list,
epochs=epochs,
shuffle=True,
verbose=1,
validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

print('Training time: %s' % (time.time()-t))
```

The only difference is my code uses one-hot encoded labels but the example does not. When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/32
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\xxx\code1.py", line 433, in <module>
    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2943, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1919, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 560, in call
    ctx=ctx)

  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)

InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[16,16] labels_size=[32,16]
     [[{{node PartitionedCall/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3780]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I suspect the "SupervisedContrastiveLoss" class needs to be modified to support training with one-hot encoded labels.

Comment: Hi @shiva. The last layer output shape of your model (logits), should match with your labels shape. As I can understand from your code,  last layer has `projection_units` neurons. I don't know what the value it has, however looks like it is not 2 (I guess it is 16), and this is incompatible with your labels, which their shape is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should convert the one-hot encoded labels to integer indices and pass them into the `model.fit()` method.

In case you want to do this conversion inside the loss, you can add this line before the return statement in the `__call__()` method of `SupervisedContrastiveLoss` class.

```
labels = tf.argmax(labels, axis=1)  # converting one-hot labels to integer indices
```

Note - Though very small, this is unnecessary overhead in compute time during model training.